# How to check if an UPDATE mysqli query is correctly executed?

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update, prepared-statement

Here is my case:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE user SET password = ? WHERE username = ? AND password = ?';
if($stmt->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $newPass, $_SESSION['username'], $oldPass);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Now, how can I see if the UPDATE query is successfully executed? And more precisely how can I see if the old password and username are correct so that I can store the new password?
I've tried by doing this:

```
$res = $stmt->execute();
echo 'Result: '.$res;
```

But I always get:

```
Result: 1
```

even if the old password is not correct.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A query which updates no rows is NOT an error condition. It's simply a succesful query that didn't change anything. To see if an update actually did change anything, you have to use [mysqli_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

Comment: Another great option is [$mysqli->info](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.info.php), which I employ for feedback on `UPDATE` queries.

Comment: A good sample of how to use $mysqli->info is on: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php#116152

Comment: This will returns 0 even if not matches any record from the 'WHERE' clause (for example, if you already deleted the record before to run this).

Comment: @JuanAntonioTubío That's a good way to actually check. Sadly there is not a built-in function for that :(

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `affected_rows` function of the MySQL extension you are using. This will return 0 if the query failed because no rows matched, -1 if an error occurred, or a positive number showing the number of rows that were changed.

Answer (score 3):

Try use `mysqli_affected_rows()` to get the number of affected rows.

Answer (score 2):

```
 mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE Language SET Status=1 WHERE Percentage > 50");
 printf("Affected rows (UPDATE): %d\n", mysqli_affected_rows($link));
```

Try that.

Comment: It may be a good idea to provide explanation on how exactly this works, as a user reading this answer in the future may not understand it or have the context required to understand it.

Comment: Okay you are right ,but in this case my answer based on the first question